# Rollback is not working in oracle using liquibase

Tags: oracle, maven, liquibase

I'm new to Liquibase. I can able to update(changeset which has create table) to the Oracle database using liquibase. while doing update i've created the tag also. But when i try to rollback the updated changes(ie dropping the created table)using the tag. The table was not dropped.

I'm using liquibase-maven plugin 3.4.2. Below are the code in maven.

```
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
  <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
  <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.2</version>
   <executions>
   <execution>
    <id>execution1</id>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <configuration>

                 <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/changelog.xml</changeLogFile>  
                 <rollbackTag>checkpoint</rollbackTag>  

                     <driver>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.86.24.2:1521:claim</url>
                    <username>Test</username>
                    <password>Test</password>  


        </configuration>
         <goals>

           <goal>rollback</goal>   
           <!--  <goal>rollbackSQL</goal>   -->

         </goals>
    </execution> 
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Below are my changelog.xml while rolling back the database.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <databaseChangeLog xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"></databaseChangeLog>
```

I tried with "rollbackSQL" . But the query to drop table has not be created.

find the below code.

```
-- *********************************************************************
-- Rollback to 'checkpoint' Script
-- *********************************************************************
-- Change Log: src/main/resources/changelog.xml
-- Ran at: 2/10/16 6:24 PM
-- Against: TEST@jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.86.24.2:1521:claim
-- Liquibase version: 3.4.2
-- *********************************************************************

SET DEFINE OFF;

-- Lock Database
UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED = 1, LOCKEDBY = 'KannanSDTW864', LOCKGRANTED = to_timestamp('2016-02-10 18:24:08.593', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') WHERE ID = 1 AND LOCKED = 0;

-- Release Database Lock
UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED = 0, LOCKEDBY = NULL, LOCKGRANTED = NULL WHERE ID = 1;
```

[Entries in the DATABASECHANGELOG table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXWV9.png)

Please help me to fix the issues.

Comment: Do you have autocommit turned on?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Can you edit your question and elaborate a bit more about the error that come up?

Comment: Please post a command that you are using to run liquibase and output.

Comment: Hi Alex-  Thanks for reply. I've checked Autocommit is in off.

Comment: Could you also add a content of DATABASECHANGELOG table?

Comment: Hi - I've attached the image  link  for Databasechangelog table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Liquibase doc:
http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/rollback.html

> Tag
>
> Specifying a tag to rollback to will roll back all change-sets that
>   were executed against the target database after the given tag was
>   applied.

But your createTable action is not after the tag "checkpoint", but is marked with this tag itself. If you want to rollback this action you need to have a tagDatabase in separate changeset before createTable.

Also why are you using empty changelog for rollback? It should contains changes that you used for update command (create table, etc).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Now i can able to rollback the changes using the seperate changeset for tagDatabase before performing the update to the database.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be working as designed, as far as I can tell. You have an empty changelog table, so no changes have been deployed. Therefore, there are no changes to roll back.

Comment: Thanks for your comments now i can able to rollback the changes-Sangeetha