# Auto rollback not working for liquibase on Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, maven, liquibase, postgresql-9.6

I am using postgres DB:

Maven pom.xml:

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
        http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">`enter code here`

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>`enter code here`

    <groupId>testing</groupId>
    <artifactId>CubeGenerator</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CubeGenerator</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <changeLogFile>/pgdb/lb/changelog.postgresql.sql</changeLogFile>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/deldb</url>
                    <username>rolldel</username>
                    <password>rolldel</password>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>updateSQL</goal>
                            <goal>futureRollbackSQL</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Liquibase.properties:

```
[postgres@pgtest lb]$ cat liquibase.properties
driver: org.postgresql.Driver
classpath: /pgdb/lb/postgresql-42.1.1.jre6.jar
changeLogFile:/pgdb/lb/changelog.postgresql.sql
url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/deldb
username: rolldel
password: rolldel
```

Changelog:

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset postgres:1-1
CREATE TABLE action (acn_id numeric(10) NOT NULL, trg_id numeric(10) NOT NULL, act_id numeric(10) NOT NULL, acn_configured_pig_id numeric(10) NOT NULL, acn_running_pig_id numeric(10), acn_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, acn_order_no numeric(10) NOT NULL, system_generated_fl CHAR(1), acn_delete_fl CHAR(1) NOT NULL, acn_version_id numeric(10) NOT NULL, ptn_id numeric(10) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE action_pin (anp_id numeric(10) NOT NULL, cmp_id numeric(10) NOT NULL, act_id numeric(10) NOT NULL, anp_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, anp_input_fl CHAR(1) NOT NULL, anp_order_no numeric(10) NOT NULL, system_generated_fl CHAR(1), anp_delete_fl CHAR(1) NOT NULL, anp_version_id numeric(10) NOT NULL, ptn_id numeric(10) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE action_pin_connection (apc_id numeric(10) NOT NULL, apc_from_acn_id numeric(10), apc_from_anp_id numeric(10), apc_from_trg_id numeric(10), apc_from_trp_id numeric(10), apc_to_acn_id numeric(10) NOT NULL, apc_to_anp_id numeric(10) NOT NULL, system_generated_fl CHAR(1), apc_delete_fl CHAR(1) NOT NULL, apc_version_id numeric(10) NOT NULL, ptn_id numeric(10) NOT NULL);
```

The liquibase update is working, but liquibase rollback is not working.

If I add `--rollback` drop table in changelog then it is working.

However, why is auto `rollback` not working for create table SQL?

Answer (score 1):

That changelog does not look like valid YAML to me.

Liquibase cannot automatically create rollback for changes written in SQL. That would require an SQL parser (for each of the SQL dialects).

If you want Liquibase to automatically generate rollback, use the [`createTable`](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/create_table.html) change.

Comment: I created changelog in xml format and auto rollback works. Thanks Laurenz.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a tag to rollback to will roll back all change-sets that were executed against the target database after the given tag was applied. i think suitable answer is available : 
you can refer below stackoverflow link Answered by `dbf` 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35370538/8363483

Comment: I tried with the tag

deldb=# UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOG SET TAG = 'version_1.1' WHERE DATEEXECUTED = (SELECT MAX(DATEEXECUTED) FROM (SELECT DATEEXECUTED FROM DATABASECHANGELOG) AS X);

[postgres@pgtest lb]$ java -jar liquibase.jar rollbackSQL version_1.0
Unexpected error running Liquibase: No inverse to liquibase.change.core.RawSQLChange created